# How to test if a mob is dead to execute a command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So i am making a 1.9.4 adventure map but then i spotted an AMAZING one vanilla minecraft command block person called IJAMinecraft! He makes the best commands and one of my favorite one commands was "Entity 303". In one part, about 8 slimes spawns around the Boss and once you shoot them all dead, the boss with execute a title and then teleport you into a platform. This could be very effective in my adventure map and was wondering how to be able to do this.

Comment: Are you asking how to find the command? It seems likely the maker of the command would post it somewhere.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 0):

Have an unconditional, repeating, always active command block with `/testfor @a {Inventory:[{id:minecraft:slimeball, Count:8}]}`, connected to a conditional, impulse, needs redstone command block with the command you want to run (in your case, the title, I recommend from http://minecraft.tools/en/title.php) and a chain, unconditional, always active command block with the `/tp @p x y z` command.

Answer (score 0):

Have a /scoreboard command with a score for killing slimes within a team then use chain command blocks or comparators to teleport and create the title command.

Another method would be to test for all slimes within the area using a |repeat|unconditional|always active| command block hooked up to a comparator that triggers the title/tp whatnot. The testfor command could be executed by the player or the boss